# Errors with the Apache Email Validator

Tags: java, email, apache-commons, email-validation

**What I'm Trying To Do:** Try to see if an email is valid using the Apache email validator.  I used this as basic code to test if it works:

```
    import org.apache.commons.validator.*;
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String email = "example@gmail.com";

        EmailValidator emailvalidator = new EmailValidator();

        if(emailvalidator.isValid(email)) {
            System.out.println("Email is valid");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Email is invalid");
        }

    }

}
```

**The Problem:** I'm  getting an error with the EmailValidator constructor "The constructor EmailValidator() is not visible".  Which causes the whole program to not work.

**My Question:** How can I fix this error.  Please be very detailed as I am quite new to Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are seeing this error because, the default constructor is made private but the docs do provide a getInstance() method. Try the following code, it should work.

```
    import org.apache.commons.validator.*;
    public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String email = "example@gmail.com";

            EmailValidator emailvalidator = EmailValidator.getInstance();

            if(emailvalidator.isValid(email)) {
                System.out.println("Email is valid");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Email is invalid");
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Upvote for adding it in my code.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI - in new versions of the library (i.e. 1.6) the email validator in org.apache.commons.validator is deprecated.  You should use the one located under org.apache.commons.validator.routines

Comment: import org.apache.commons.validator.*; gives error on apache Netbeans IDE 20, what is the latest technique for validating email addresses?